# Get ID from table inside session user id

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to get value from userID column in my table inside the sessein array.

in my register class I have the following code:

```
<?php

class Users {
public $username = null;
public $password = null; 
public $salt = "Zo4rU5Z1YyKJAASY0PT6EUg7BBYdlEhPaNLuxAwU8lqu1ElzHv0Ri7EM6irpx5w";
public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
if( isset( $data['username'] ) ) $this->username = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['username'] ) );
if( isset( $data['password'] ) ) $this->password = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['password'] ) );
}

public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
//store the parameters
$this->__construct( $params );
}

public function userLogin() {
$success = false;
try{
$con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
$stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
$stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );


$stmt->execute();

$valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if( $valid ) {
$success = true;
$_SESSION['userID'] = $user->user_id;

}
```

for which syntaxis I am not very sure that it will sessionize the UserID value of the logged user.

and in the login where the array is created I have

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once("config.php"); //include the settings/configuration
?>

<?php 
//else look at the database and see if he entered the correct details
} else {
session_start();
$usr = new Users;
$usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );
if( $usr->userLogin() ) {
header( 'Location: cursos.php' ) ;
$_SESSION["loggedIn"] = true;
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
$_SESSION['userID'] = $_POST['userID'];
```

but it gives me every time NULL result how to fix it ?

Comment: Have you started a session in your script?

Comment: Can you post more code? We should be looking at experts that deal with sessions.

Comment: After setting the user is try print_r($_SESSION), what does it say?

Comment: I am making var_dump on session and it gives me this: array(4) { ["userID"]=> NULL ["loggedIn"]=> bool(true) ["username"]=> string(9) "vladicorp" ["password"]=> string(3) "123" }

Answer (score 0):

first of all if you're posting the form you should use $_POST['userID'] and first check it if you retrieving the value in your $_POST['userID'] then you have to start session like this

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userID'] = $_POST['userID']
```

but the first one code i understand you're using codeigniter or OOP $user->user_id the first $user is your variable and second one is user_id which may be your access modifier also check $user->user_id it has value then do same

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['userID'] = $user->user_id;
```

Comment: this is the part that defnes user_id but with it is not working at all: $valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if( $valid ) {
 
$user = $stmt->fetchObj();

if( $user->user_id > 0 ) {

Comment: at the end this is  a guess how it can be achived I am not sure if this is the right direction, to get variable and to put it inside the session array